# How to remove .php extension and add slash on the url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my current .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

it is works only in removing .php extension

from 
`http://localhost/mysite/news.php?category=cat1&id=1` 
to 
`http://localhost/mysite/news/cat1/1/`

and from

`http://localhost/mysite/news.php?category=cat1&year=2011&month=10&day=25&id=1` 
to 
`http://localhost/mysite/news/2011/10/25/1`

How to write complete .htaccess for the clean url above?

Answer (score 3):

Try This

**RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]**

for example

> http://www.exapmle.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 2):

Add an optional / to your pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite news articles and pass news id as a GET parameter to news.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/mysite/news/(\d+)/?$ /mysite/news.php?newsid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# rewrite all other page requests to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/mysite/(.*)/?$ /mysite/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: its not working when I access the page http://localhost/mysite/news/1  it returns to 404 page

Comment: That's because your rewrite is now looking for /news/1.php in your document root - is there such a file?

Comment: nope 1 should be the news id http://localhost/mysite/news/newsid/ I want the out like that. my pages are index.php,about.php,news.php only the news page should be like this http://localhost/mysite/news/newsid/ and other should be http://localhost/mysite/about or http://localhost/mysite/about/

Comment: hmm - have update my answer to match this new information (you should put this kind of thing in your question)

Answer (score 1):

You could just try a simple `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ $1.php
```

This tacks on `.php` to any file-looking url: `example.com/somethin` becomes `example.com/somethin.php`, `example.com/something/else/` becomes `example.com/somethin/else.php`, etc.

The only problem with this is if you try to access an actual folder, like `example.com/images` or something.

Comment: its not working when I access the page http://localhost/mysite/news/1  it returns to 404 page