# Rewrite rule to remove ".php" extension and add trailing slash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove .php extension and add slash on the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858253/how-to-remove-php-extension-and-add-slash-on-the-url)

I need to put in my .htacces (which is now blank) something to remove .php from all of my url's and to also force a trailing slash.

---

I know this KIND of question(usually way more specific) has been asked numerouse times, but I swear I can't find an answer to work for me.

Weird thing is, I used to have an .htaccess code to do exactly what I want, and I swear I got the code from here... but I lost it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858253/how-to-remove-php-extension-and-add-slash-on-the-url , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133111/mod-rewrite-add-trailing-slash , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321214/how-to-remove-all-php-extension-from-a-dir-and-all-of-its-subdirectories

Comment: @DigitalPrecision he's not using symfony, how is this relevant?

Comment: @Flukey: Figured the `<FilesMatch "^(fe|be)?(_dev)?$">ForceType application/x-httpd-php</FilesMatch>` may have been of some use.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#skip existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
#capture every url path request ending with a slash 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$ [NC]
#and rewritten to .php with that name. Assumes all .php files are in the root
RewriteRule . %1.php [NC,L]    


#add a trailing slash to all urls without one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+[^/]) [NC]
RewriteRule .  %1/  [L,R=301]

#remove .php from all urls and also add a trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)\.php  /$1/  [L,R=301,NC]
```

Edit:
Modified above to rewrite requests with a path suffixed with a slash to  a.php of the same name.  Note that this assumes that all the .php files are in the root directory

Comment: is that in order? -because with my htaccess written like that, IE,FF; they wont even go to my pages.

Comment: Ok I wrote it: RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+[^/]) [NC] RewriteRule (.*)\.php /$1/ [L,R=301,NC] - it works(removes.php and adds trailing slash), but I get a 404. i dont want that. what do i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595/htaccess-code-to-remove-extension-and-addforce-trailing-slash[/link] is where the answer is. thanks anyways